# Crawlers unable to index ui-router links of AngularJS

Tags: angular, indexing, angular-ui-router, web-crawler

I am developing a webapplication with AngularJS, using ui-router with "ui-sref" links.
The links does not get indexed by web crawlers.

Links are in the following form

```
< a ui-sref="aboutMe">link< /a>
```

And `$stateprovider` looks like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('aboutMe', {
        templateUrl: 'aboutMe/aboutMe.html',
        controller: 'aboutMeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'aboutMe'
    })
```

A URL is not displayed for each link when clicked (This is the way I want it).
 For example the website's URL will always be www.websitename.com no matter which ui-sref link was clicked, and never www.websitename.com/linkname.

Due to achieving this, how can a Crawler or "web-page-scorer" detect these links? Can I somehow set meta-data for these dynamic links to be detected?

Comment: Does it change the link? and if you use $state.go(StateName) works??

Comment: Can you show what happens after clicking the state?

Comment: @KenrySanchez 
$state.go(StateName) works fine.

When an ui-sref link is clicked the associated HTML file of state is loaded into the   
<div ui-view></div>
  
Intentionally the line url '/aboutMe' is not included, so website.com/aboutMe is not displayed nor can it be navigated to, as desired.